# Deploying Eclipse Plugin RCP App on External Server

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Pardon my ignorance on this topic but I am ignorant in this field and have come to own the migration of an app because the java developer couldn't figure it out. The original developer is no longer with the company.

We have a standalone SQL Server Database driven GUI app developed as an Eclipse plug-in RCP app currently running in full gusto on a desktop. We need to migrate it to a server based off a datacenter.

Just plain zip - unzip copy jars and config files did not work - the app is throwing a bunch of unrelated error messages which include, but not limited to:

```
     !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
     !STACK 0
```

So, at this point I am wondering if I should build the app from scratch on the new server.

So I am hoping the experts here can guide me if that is indeed the case for plug-in apps developed in Eclipse i.e Do they need to be build using Eclipse or Maven when deploying to external Servers?

I understand without looking at the specifics, it is impossible to answer, but I'm wondering if it is a standard operating procedure to re-build the plug-in apps on the Server to deploy? If so, are there any pitfalls or gotchas I need to watch for?

Any guidance in this regard will greatly be appreciated.

TIA for your time,

---

Adding entries from the log file

```
  !SESSION 2015-07-27 16:59:38.365 -----------------------------------------------
  eclipse.buildId=unknown
  java.version=1.6.0_21
  java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
  BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
  Framework arguments:  --startup -consoleLog             plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
```

Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 --startup -consoleLog plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar

```
   !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-07-27 17:00:00.720
   !MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
   !STACK 0
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at             com.tax.prxy.analytics.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.initialize(ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor.java:63)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.internalBasicInitialize(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:188)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$28.runWithException(Workbench.java:1526)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2537)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at com.tax.prxy.analytics.Application.start(Application.java:23)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

Comment: Eclipse plugins will only run in Eclipse, they don't run anywhere else.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your note. I apologize this is a Plug-in RCP Product which I understand can run as a standalone application?

Comment: Yes an RCP is just a standalone app. Show us the earliest log entries which will probably show the root cause if the issues

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 for offering to look at the log entries. Updated the OP with the entries. Also, just so you know, I did some research on the unhandled event loop and added the -consoleLog to the config file at startup and launched the app again, but I didnt see any other entries show up. Also, I tried to look into the null pointer, but the initalize was generic, so didnt get anywhere there either. Thanks again for your time.